# How to start Notepad++ from a Windows 10 batch file?

Tags: windows, batch, notepad++, ms-dos

When I Google this, I get pages about running Notepad++ from the command line, running batch files from Notepad++, and pages that start by explaining how I set my path variable.

I am not allowed to set my path variable on my work machine (don't get me STARTED). So I would like to create a batch file that will run Notepad++ and put it in a directory off the root (I'd put it in the root, but am not allowed to do that either) so that I have a short command to start it.

I've tried:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" %*

'C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe' %*

"'C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe'" %*

C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe %*

'C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' %*

"C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe" %*
```

Comment: Are you sure its in the 32-bit (x86) folder?

Comment: The first option works fine for me (Windows 10). What error are you getting?

Comment: (sigh) do *I* feel stupid. It USED to be there, but is now in the other (64-bit) folder. thanks, folks.

Answer (score 0):

There are both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Notepad++ for Windows. I use the 32-bit because there are 32-bit extensions for Notepad++ I want which won't work in the 64-bit version.

Here's NN.BAT which works on either 32-bit or 64-bit Notepad++, and opens a specified file.

```
REM NN.BAT  Launches Notepad++ whether in 32-bit or 64-bit Program Files directory   
C:\Progra~1\Notepad++\notepad++.exe %1  
C:\Progra~2\Notepad++\notepad++.exe %1
```